# Unable to remote desktop using failover cluster name

Tags: high-availability, cluster, failover, failovercluster

I am using Microsoft Failover Cluster and I have 2 nodes - say node1 & node2. The nodes are successfully accessed by remote desktop.
but the cluster name is not accessible.

The cluster name is pinging fine, not listening to RDP port 3389 (Filtered).

Kindly help me in getting access to the cluster name.

Comment: I don't see how this would be useful. Even if you got it working you'd only connect to one of the cluster hosts so why not just connect to each cluster host directly.